# How to catch images with blank dimensions?

Tags: php, regex, image, height, width

I've created a [WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/specify-image-dimensions/) that inserts `width` and `height` attributes to all images, for example:

```
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50">
- to -
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" width="100" height="50">
```

Yet, when there are images that have blank dimensions (for both `width` and `height`), my code doesn't doesn't catch it, for example:

```
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" width="" height="">
```

However, when there is only one blank dimension, my plugin does catch it. The following two examples will work:

```
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" width="">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" height="">
```

[Here's the source code](https://github.com/factmaven/specify-image-dimensions/blob/master/specify-image-dimensions.php). On line 43 ([#](https://github.com/factmaven/specify-image-dimensions/blob/master/specify-image-dimensions.php#L43)), this is the logic I'm using to determine if an image is missing a `width`/`height`:

```
if ( ! in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) || ! in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) ) {
```

I've tried the following updated logic, but it doesn't work:

```
if ( # Images with no width/height
    ! in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) || ! in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) ||
    # Images with blank width/height
    ( in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) && in_array( '""', $img[1] ) ) || ( in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) && in_array( '""', $img[1] ) )
) {
```

Am I in the right area? What am I doing wrong in my logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searching for the value in the `1` index where I should have looked in the `2` index which contains the values:

```
if ( # Images with no width/height
    ! in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) || ! in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) ||
    # Images with blank width/height
    ( in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) && in_array( '""', $img[2] ) ) || ( in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) && in_array( '""', $img[2] ) )
) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the `width=""` part of `<img ... width="">` result in the strings `width` and `""` as elements for `$img`? Which is a match, and a non-empty at that, so a `! in_array` is probably wrong here.

Your code would get executed, if no width/height attributes at all were present.

Just check the concrete values of the match for all widths and heights, and react the same as in your code if it evaluates to string `""`

edit: Your updated logic assumed the two captured groups are one string, but they are not. So instead of `in_array( 'width=""', $img[1] )` you would need `(in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) and in_array( '""', $img[1] ))`, plus the same for height, respectively.

Comment: I see, makes sense. I've updated my logic as you mentioned which I've shown in my original question. However, it still doesn't work on images with blank dimensions. Am I implementing it incorrectly?